# Refer image in a jar file with relative path

Tags: java, maven

I have a MAVEN project where I have images in the resources directory. Is there a way to refer those images using relative path? I am trying something like

```
File file = new File("/images/abc.jpg");
```

That does not work. Rather it is looking for this path in the directory where jar is deployed/placed. Any leads?

Comment: You have tagged this 'eclipse-plugin'. If this is an Eclipse Plug-in you are developing you should look at the `FileLocator` class.

Comment: @greg-449 This 'eclipse-plugin' seems to be a mistake. Removing it.